# Ruby gem 'tcp_timeout' failed to suppress raising error

Tags: ruby

I wrote a script using 'socket' that connects to a host and port and because socket.timeout doesn't really work I tried using the 'tcp_timeout' gem that works properly but I can't seem to suppress the error raised when connect/read/write timeout happens. Any idea where am I wrong?

```
begin
  socket = TCPTimeout::TCPSocket.new(server, port, connect_timeout: 6, read_timeout: 6)
  unless socket.read(12) =~ /^SMTH\n$/
    puts "[!] #{server} banner error"
    exit(1)
  end
rescue TCPTimeout::SocketTimeout => err
  puts "[!] #{server} Timeout"
  exit(1)
end
```

The error raised, as expected is a read timeout error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/tcp_timeout-0.1.1/lib/tcp_timeout.rb:160:in `select_timeout': read timeout (TCPTimeout::SocketTimeout)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/tcp_timeout-0.1.1/lib/tcp_timeout.rb:108:in `block in read'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/tcp_timeout-0.1.1/lib/tcp_timeout.rb:107:in `loop'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/tcp_timeout-0.1.1/lib/tcp_timeout.rb:107:in `read'
        from ./myhost.rb:67:in `<main>'
```

I tried even:

```
rescue TCPTimeout::SocketTimeout, StandardError, Timeout::Error => err
```

Same thing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of tcp_timeout here; your code looks correct. This snippet works as expected (for me):

```
require 'tcp_timeout'
begin
  socket = TCPTimeout::TCPSocket.new('stackoverflow.com', 80, read_timeout: 1)
  socket.read(100)
rescue TCPTimeout::SocketTimeout => e
  puts 'Rescued!', e
end
```

If you can find a snippet that fails reliably against a public server please file a bug: https://github.com/lann/tcp-timeout-ruby/issues

Comment: Yes, the script works as expected, my problem is I want to hide the raised error and just show my `puts "[!] #{server} Timeout"`. I'm on Ruby 1.9.3-p551

Comment: @Lann do we NEED to give the length we're expecting back on reads? I'm trying to just read back however many bytes are available, preferably with a maxlength, but can't see how 
*EDIT: Nevermind! readpartial method does what I need :)